# How to obtain a bipartitioned circular interval graph from a circular interval graph?

Tags: graph-theory

A circular interval graph is a proper circular arc graph. The latter is defined as an intersection graph of a set of arcs on a circle such that it has a vertex for every arc in the set and an edge between every pair of vertices corresponding to arcs that intersect. Most importantly, no arc is properly contained by another.

According to Bruhn et al. we can obtain a bipartitioned circular interval graph from any circular interval graph.

> For any circular interval graph, partition its vertex set and delete
>   every edge with both endvertices in the same class.

How is the partition made? Is it a random partition? Or one that minimizes the number of edges to delete?

Let’s consider the graph (a circular arc graph) and its arc model in figure 01.

Figure 01
[image]

Following the steps described in Bruhn et al., we obtain a partition such as shown in figure 02. Then we proceed to delete edges such as every edge with both its endvertices in the same class is to be deleted. In the case of this graph, there’s only one edge to delete which is (1,7).

Figure 02
[image]

After deleting the edge we obtain the following graph $G’=(V,E’)$ shown in figure 03.

Figure 03
[image]

**Question:** *Is the obtained graph $G’$ the corresponding bipartitioned circular interval graph of the graph $G$? Are the steps described in Bruhn et al. correctly followed?*